# Social user login

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

This is my first Laravel package.  It uses hybrid Auth package to authenticate users using their social network accounts. It can retrieve information to store in a local database.

Its purpose is to be able to link several social networks accounts into one single user.  That way, if you login with Facebook or Twitter, you will have the same account.

[Package GIT](https://github.com/caalaniz1/LorisLogin)

[Main Controller](https://github.com/caalaniz1/LorisLogin/blob/master/src/controllers/LorisLoginController.php)

```
<?php

class LorisLogin extends BaseController {

    private $success_messages = array(
        'newSProfile' => 'NewProfile added successfully',
    );
    private $error_messages = array(
        'notFound' => 'Aparently the social network profile that you tried to
        access with is not in our database, please login using your local 
        account or previosly synced social profile.',
        'incorrectCred' => 'Incorrect username or password please try again',
        'Found' => 'Try to click on a social network button to login or signup',
        'registered' => 'This social Profile is already linked with your account',
        'registeredToOther' => 'This social Profile is already associated with  an other',
    );

    /**
     * This function must be exclusively used when creating a local account
     * using a social profile, it will generate and return an unused 
     * username for a user.
     * 
     * @param string $username
     * @return string $username
     */
    private static function nameUser($username) {
        $num = 00;
        $dup = NULL;
        //is username cannot be saved the username is taked by other user
        while (!User::where('username', '=', $username)->get()->isEmpty()) {
            //TRy to take the last duplicate of the number
            $dup = User::where('username', 'LIKE', $username . '-sL__')
                    ->orderBy('username', 'desc')
                    ->first();
            //if theres a hit the the number and increase it
            if ($dup != NULL) {
                $num = (int) substr($dup->username, -2);
                $num++;
            }
            //try a new username
            $username = $username . '-sL' . sprintf('%02d', $num);
        }
        return $username;
    }

    /**
     * Tries to connect to a social network provider is success return
     * the profile else trow expection
     * 
     * @param string $network
     * Network to connect to ex. 'facebook', 'twitter'
     * @return HybridAuth profile object
     */
    public static function loginSocial($network = NULL) {
        //config file
        $_config = include app_path() . '/config/hybridauth.php';
        //Get current Route
        $route_name = Route::currentRouteName();
        $action = Input::get('action');

        // check URL segment
        if ($action == "auth") {
            // process authentication
            try {
                Hybrid_Endpoint::process();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // redirect back to http://URL/social/
                return Redirect::route($route_name);
            }
            return;
        }
        try {
            $network = Input::get('network');
            // create a HybridAuth object
            $_config['base_url'] = route($route_name) . '?action=auth';
            $socialAuth = new Hybrid_Auth($_config);
            // authenticate with Google
            $provider = $socialAuth->authenticate($network);
            // fetch user profile
            $userProfile = $provider->getUserProfile();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // exception codes can be found on HybBridAuth's web site
            return $e->getMessage();
        }

        $provider->logout();
        return $userProfile;
    }

    /**
     * Try to log in using a social profile, if is not found on the DB
     * It redirects to Sigup 
     * 
     * @array Mixed
     * 
     */
    public function loginWithSocial() {
        try {
            $userProfile = $this->loginSocial();
            $profile = SocialProfile::find($userProfile->identifier);
            if ($profile != NULL) {
                $user = $profile->user()->getResults();
                Auth::login($user);
                return Redirect::route('admin-user-landing');
            } else {
                echo $this->error_messages['notFound'];
                return Redirect::route('signup')
                                ->with('message', $this->error_messages['notFound']
                );
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Try to Authenticate a user using local credentials
     * 
     * @return Redirect
     */
    public function loginWithLocal() {
        $username = Input::get('username');
        $password = Input::get('password');
        if (Auth::attempt(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password))) {
            return Redirect::route('admin-users-landing');
        }
        return Redirect::route('login')
                        ->with('message', $this->error_messages['incorrectCred']);
    }

    /**
     * Check if Social Profile Exists in DB if not it will create a new local 
     * account and a new Social Profile and Link them togueter.
     * 
     * @return Redirect or Exeption
     */
    public function signupWithSocial() {
        try {
            $userProfile = $this->loginSocial();
            $profile = SocialProfile::find($userProfile->identifier);
            echo var_dump($profile);
            if ($profile == NULL) {
                //Generate username and password
                $username = $this->nameUser($userProfile->displayName);
                $password = Str::random(8);
                //Create new User
                $user = new User;
                $user->username = $username;
                $user->password = Hash::make($password);
                $user->save();
                //generate new socialProfile
                $sprofile = new SocialProfile;
                $sprofile->identifier = $userProfile->identifier;
                $sprofile->provider = Input::get('network');
                $sprofile->user_id = $user->id;
                $sprofile->save();
                //login
                Auth::login($user);
                //redirect back to admin 
                //include message about changing password
                return Redirect::action('LorisLogin@addLocalProfile', array('network' => Input::get('network')));
            } else {
                return Redirect::action("LorisLogin@loginWithSocial", array('network' => Input::get('network')));
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Creates or Updates local Profile
     * 
     * @return \Exception or Redirect
     */
    public function addLocalProfile() {
        try {
            $user = Auth::user();
            //user profile
            $up = $this->loginSocial();

            //try to get a local profile
            $localProfile = Auth::user()->localProfile()->getResults();
            //if it does not exist create a new one
            if (!$localProfile) {
                $localProfile = new LocalProfile;
            }
            //fill/update
            $localProfile->first_name = $up->firstName;
            $localProfile->last_name = $up->lastName;
            $localProfile->description = $up->description;
            $localProfile->gender = $up->gender;
            $localProfile->photo_url = $up->photoURL;
            $localProfile->birth_day = $up->birthDay;
            $localProfile->birth_month = $up->birthMonth;
            $localProfile->birth_year = $up->birthYear;
            $localProfile->email = $up->email;
            $localProfile->address = $up->address;
            $localProfile->country = $up->country;
            $localProfile->city = $up->city;
            $localProfile->zip = $up->zip;
            $localProfile->user_id = $user->id;

            //save profile
            $localProfile->save();
            //link to user
            $user->local_profile_id = $localProfile->id;
            //save User
            $user->save();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e;
        }
        return Redirect::route('admin-user-landing');
    }

    /**
     * associates a new Social Profile to a user account
     * 
     * @return Void
     */
    public function linkSocialProfile() {
        try {
            //get user
            $user = Auth::user();
            //get social Profile
            $socialProfile = $this->loginSocial();
            //check if Profile is registered already
            $dbsp = SocialProfile::find((int) $socialProfile->identifier);
            if ($dbsp != NULL) {
                if ($dbsp->user()->getResults() == $user) {
                    return Redirect::route('admin-user-landing')
                                    ->with('message', $this->error_messages['registered']);
                } else {
                    return Redirect::route('admin-user-landing')
                                    ->with('message', $this->error_messages['registeredToOther']);
                }
            }
            //Add social profile to DB 
            $user->socialProfiles()->create(array(
                'provider' => Input::get('network'),
                'identifier' => $socialProfile->identifier,
                'user_id' => $user->id,
            ));
            return Redirect::route('admin-user-landing')
                            ->with('message', $this->success_messages['newSProfile'])
                            ->with('sucess', true);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e;
        }
    }

    public function fillLocalProfile() {

    }

}
```